# git-credential-store using git-credential-cache--daemon

Tags: git, git-push

I am using [git-credential-store](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-credential-store.html)
with my repository. However I noticed when I run `git push` it launches
`git-credential-cache--daemon` and will not close it until I close the terminal.

1. If I am using `git-credential-store` and my credentials are saved in
   `~/.git-credentials`, why is this program needed?
2. Even if this program is needed, why doesn't it close after `git push` completes?

```
$ git config --global credential.helper
store
```

Comment: Can you describe how you configured your credential helper to be git-credential-store?

Comment: I assume you already did an `git credential-cache--daemon exit` to flush it out and try again?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The daemon can be killed like this

```
kill -7 $(ps | awk /daemon/,NF=1)
```

However I have noticed with my current version this problem has been resolved.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.0.4
```

Answer (score 2):

For the life of me looking at the git source code I cannot figure out why the `git-credential-cache--daemon` would have started if you configured git to use `git-credential-store`. Can you describe how you configured your credential helper to be [git-credential-store](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-credential-store.html)? What you should have done is the following -

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

When I used this configuration on my machine, the `git-credential-cache--daemon` was never launched.

Regarding the second piece of the question, the `git-credential-cache--daemon` opens when it is called as a helper to `fill` a credential request and stays open for a default time out period of 900 seconds. You can modify the timeout behavior so it will close quicker by changing the option in your config. It stays open to quickly serve requests from memory for further authentication.

More details on the [git credentials API here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/api-credentials.html).

Comment: (Just noticed that the second link here is broken - can someone discover how it can be fixed? I looked through [this folder](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/), but could not see anything relevant).